# How I change my Site URI in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, drush

In Drupal 7 I put in settings.php this:

```
$base_url = 'http://mysite.local';
```

And when I run:

```
$ drush uli
http://mysite.local/user/reset/1/1460387746/mTqwCdJ7hi_pmrPRuFOScYwFtoHTmVAW07MV23O3UVk/login
```

The url generated will be fine.

In Drupal 8 I check and still [there](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!globals.api.php/global/base_url/8).

But in my Drupal 8 site, when I try run:
$ drush uli

I got:

```
mysite does not appear to be a resolvable hostname or IP, not starting browser. You may need to use the --uri option in your command or site alias to indicate the correct URL of this site.                          [warning]
http://mysite/user/reset/1/1460387905/ntObZiBxAnYdgGoc9jLqCIeQYpN_WjO04UlXcfSNZMo
```

I know I can do this:
$ drush uli --uri='mysite.local'

But much work.

Too I can do this with some drush config.

Then, how I do this like Drupal 7 in settings.php?

Answer (score 12):

Since Drupal 8 uses Symfony's request stack which generates the base url, some things are not possible to do in the same manner as was possible in Drupal 7.

Instead create `sites/default/drushrc.php` and add

```
<?php

$options['uri'] = 'http://mysite.local';
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 10):

@googletorp's answer led me in the right direction (thank you!), but was not the correct answer for me.  I am on Drupal 8.6 and drush 9.7.  Instead of a drushrc.php file, a drush.yml file was needed.

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drush.yml

specifically, this configuration within it (options is a top-level element):

```
options:
  uri: 'http://mysite.local'
```

There was already a drush.yml file located at /drush/drush.yml so this is the one I used.

Comment: Hmmm I can confirm drushrc.php no longer works and also the config path /sites/default/drush.yml is no longer included by drush so it doesn't look like there's a clean way to commit this setting to version control any longer.

Answer (score 6):

for drupal 8.9 and drush 9.7.2

In the outputted list from

```
drush status
```

you will see: "Drush configs". It shows the path or paths to drush configuration files. i.e. /var/www/mysite/drush/drush.yml

in that file you can add:

```
options:
  uri: 'http://mysite.local'
```

drush should pick it up immediately, or after

```
drush cc drush
```

Comment: Very helpful as of Dec. 2020. Mine shows two files: one in home/ directory; another in the project's vendor/ directory. So for those using composer, it may be the vendor/ one, which may/may not be wise to edit.

Comment: You can also add an additional site specific drush config to define your site uri. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263954/how-to-have-an-environment-specific-drush-yml#answer-302818 for details.