# How to have an environment specific drush.yml?

Tags: drush

I'm using Drush 9. With the old drushrc.php I could easily include a local.drushrc.php that dynamically set the site url. How can I do it now?

This is similar to [How can i set site url dynamically in Drush-9?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/255586/528). However I don't want to pass the url in every Drush command. I think of something like below in ../drush/drush.yml:

```
drush:
  paths:
    config:
      - ${env.home}/local.drush.yml
```

But I'd need another variable that point to the Drupal site directory (`sites/default` in a monosite, `sites/CURRENT-SITE` in a multisite). Does such a variable exist?

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I do on my sites and it works:

### Step 1: sites/default/drush.local.yml

```yaml
options:
  uri: 'https://dev.example.com'
```

You can name this file however you want. Also, since this file varies from env to env, I ignore it with `.gitignore`. At the same time, I commit an `example.drush.local.yml`.

### Step 2: drush/drush.yml

- One level above Drupal installation, .i.e. where Drupal's `index.php`  is located, I have my `composer.json` and `vendor` directories.
- In this directory, I create a directory named `drush` and in it, I place a `drush.yml` with these contents:

```yaml
drush:
  paths:
    config:
      - web/sites/default/drush.local.yml
```

After this, I running `drush st` from that directory, will show you that the `drush.local.yml` has been detected and the site URI is set correctly.

Comment: This the correct answer. I have read a few posts on using drushrc.php and sites.php, but they did not work for me with Drupal 9.X. +1 Thanks

Comment: I second that, and what is awesome is you can use environment variables in the yml using `${env.VAR_NAME}`. I wanted this to be in my repo, so I created a file for each like `env-${env.DEPLOY_ENV}.drush.yml` so `env-stage.drush.yml` and within each file put the domain name I wanted to use. You could also try `uri: 'https://${env.VIRTUAL_HOST}'` and a single drush file if you for example had access to your URI in that manner. That would make it super dynamic.

Comment: Great answer, I was wondering how to do it in the last few days.

Answer (score 1):

Reading https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drush.yml it seems you can put a site specific drush.yml in a sites directory. It is merged with the global file(s).

PS! I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: Tested but it didn't work. I agree that it should have worked.

Comment: Try checking your own `example.drush.yml` file in case you have an older version. [The local config filename used to be different](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/cf00e0536e86801adcce08a9443e71ddf99733bc).

Comment: I'm already on Drush 9.3.0. The file `sites/default/drush.yml` is not automatically detected. I thought this was a problem with lightning, but I try with a standard distribution and I have the same result.

Comment: Confirming that I'm on Drush 9.5.2  and the documentation suggests that the first place it checks is sites/default/drush.yml but this doesnt seem to be the case, because it is not picking up the default --uri option i have configured in that file  `options:  uri:  http://mysite.test` when I run `drush uli`.  Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Even adding ```drush:
  paths:
    config:
      - ../web/sites/default/drush.yml```  into /drush/drush.yml doesnt seem to help

Comment: Hang on, this is weird. this config ^, ^^ just started working without explanation after a clean site install.  maybe drush cleared its own cache or something?

Comment: Ok, I've figured this out: For `sites/default/drush.yml` to be recognized by drush you have to run drush from the drupal root folder.   This used to not be a problem in drush 8 with sites/default/drushrc.php