# Set site URI for drush uli without 'default'

Tags: 8, drush

Versions discussed: Drupal 8.6.13, Drush 9.6.1.

This is somewhat similar to [How to have an environment specific drush.yml?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263954/how-to-have-an-environment-specific-drush-yml) except that the other thread is now four or five months out-of-date and Drush 9.6.1 doesn't seem to respect the `drush.yml` anymore.

I'm just trying to set my Site URI.

As detailed in that thread, I've tried `web/sites/default/drush.yml` as well as many other locations for the `drush.yml`, done a `drush cc drush`, and yet `drush status` still reveals an incorrect Site URI of `http://default`, showing that it is not respecting the `uri:` line in any of my `drush.yml` files.

To complicate matters, I'm using [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), so following up on some suggestions that I've gotten from the Drupal Slack that we should really be using an environment variable (namely `DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI`) have proven tricky, as I'm not exactly sure where that goes inside of the DDEV environment.

Inside the DDEV container, if I do `export DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI=http://my.ddev.local/` then everything works great, but once I quit the container or try to do things from outside it, such as `ddev exec drush uli`, things are back to the incorrect Site URI.

How can I persist this environment variable across restarts of DDEV/Docker?

Answer (score 6):

I'm writing this up for posterity, since the Slack is relatively ephemeral. Here's the current method, following [Providing custom environment variables to a container](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-environment-variables-to-a-container):

In e.g. `.ddev/docker-compose.environment.yml` put the following:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    environment:
      - DRUSH_OPTIONS_URI=http://my.ddev.local
```

Then `ddev rm` and `ddev start` to prove to see it working. (This works for `drush uli` inside the container, after `ddev ssh`.)